# Broken Image Redirects and HTAccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Let me try to explain my problem/question.

We have a Zenphoto gallery that when a user on on an Album, we provide them with some embed html that they can use on their own site.

eg
http://spoilertv.co.uk/images/fringe/season-4/promotional-episode-photos/episode-4.01-neither-here-nor-there/

This is great and works well.

However, we recently had to move an album, and this caused an issue with broken image links

see here for example
http://itsawesometv.com/blog/2011/04/07/hawaii-5-0-1-22-hoohuli-naau-poze-promotionale/

You will see that the images are broken and the links take you to a Zenphoto page saying "Object Not Found".

Now what I would like to do is to have some sort of catchall image and link redirect. So that if we have to move album again we won't get loads of 404 errors and broken image links.

eg
So that rather than displaying a broken image on the site that has embeded the old code, that they get a little icon for each broken image. This would stop the 100's of 404 errors in my server log.

Also it would be great if when they clicked on the icon, that rather than go to the Object Not Found page, that it redirects to the Gallery Homepage.

Any suggestions about how I can do this? Links/examples most welcomed.